# Is it possible to have your "local" git repo on a server?

Tags: git, workflow

My team wants to start using git.

We have plenty of server space, so the idea of each of us having a "local" repository on the server came up. This would allow our development to take place on the same server as our production tools (all in house). I've looked into this, but I can find any posts about anyone doing this before, so it may be a silly idea.

I've used git before, but only through a local branch on my own machine, that I would edit, then commit back up to the remote repository.

Is it possible edit files directly on a server (through ssh, we do this already) and then commit those files to another repository on that same server? (or a different one)

Basically, instead of having the repo on the server, and then I pull it and edit on my own machine, then push it back, my "own machine" would be files stored on another server.

Bonus advice would be how to do this using the smart-git interface, which I prefer, but is not required.

Edit: helpful answers so far! Thanks guys. I am still curious if it is possible to use smart-git to view this kind of a set up on a server, but that may need to be its own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git repositories can be hosted anywhere. On my linux machine I can make a folder, mount the folder virtually, and they add it as remote and push to it. I can also mount the 'remote' drive as a local drive, and develop locally as a dev environment, which is what you are looking for I believe.

For my private projects I just have a few hard drives in a raid 5, and I share it on my local network. I can setup git repositories and add remotes to the folders they reside in.

This question in SO might help you as well:
https://serverfault.com/questions/463811/git-clone-pull-across-local-network

Secondly, if you are committing to a local er... git remote, you can add a git *hook*, which you could then tell it to git push to *another* git repository somewhere else. There's so many different things you could do it's insane.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT: **Just a note, I can't comment so I'll put it here. If you have your remote drive mounted locally or you can access it over your network, you can open tools like smart-git *inside* that remote repository to edit it like a local project.

The way git was designed, though, is to have several different branches to develop on, so everyone has the full copy, and you just send your changes to the server, and they other people merge and they push their changes, etc. That way two people can't ever try to edit the same file at the same time. Just my two cents.

Comment: Thanks for the server-fault answer, my google-fu was not strong enough I guess, that is definitely a helpful post.

Comment: No problem! I went through these questions with myself awhile back, too. It's hard to figure out what to look for until you figure out what you need.

Comment: @Xgongiveittoya hey I edited my answer, hopefully this answers your last question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have repos on different servers, linked by `git remote add <name> <remoteurl>`, then you can pull/push/merge etc among them.

In your case, could the use of branching (`git checkout -b <newBranch>`) be a simpler and more space-efficient solution? Branching uses minimal additional server space.

Comment: So would the "dev" repos be checked out branches of the main repo? Ex: checkout the main repo to a xgonDev branch on the server?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking...branches are on the same repo (hence saving a lot of space compare to cloning a new repo).

Google 'git branching' to read up more on it.